# Window, Partition by in HIVE to get average 7-day temperatures

Tags: hive, data-partitioning, windowing

I have a dataset that has multiple temperature readings per day. I am looking to return the hottest 7-day period by average temperature.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS oshkosh; 
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS oshkosh(year STRING, month STRING, day STRING, time STRING, temp FLOAT, dewpoint FLOAT, humidity INT, sealevel FLOAT, visibility FLOAT, winddir STRING, windspeed FLOAT, gustspeed FLOAT, precip FLOAT, events STRING, condition STRING, winddirdegrees INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/user/maria_dev/final/Oshkosh' tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1"); 

SELECT o.theDate
,AVG(o.temp) over (order by o.theDate range INTERVAL 6 DAY preceding) AS Average
FROM
(SELECT CAST(to_date(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(year,'-',IF(LENGTH(month)=1,CONCAT(0,month),month),'-',IF(LENGTH(day)=1,CONCAT(0,day),day)),'yyyy-MM-dd'))) as timestamp) as theDate
,temp AS temp
FROM oshkosh
WHERE temp != -9999) as o
```

this returns the error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:38 cannot recognize input near 'range' 'INTERVAL' '6' in window_value_expression
```

I'm not sure if I want a timestamp as o.theDate because it seems that the INTERVAL 6 DAY call may not find a new day because there are 28 temperature readings for the first day of the dataset (and 44 readings for day 2, it's variable for each day).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SELECT 
    o.theDate,
    AVG(o.temp) over (order by unix_timestamp(o.theDate) range between 604800 
    preceding and current row) AS Average 
FROM
(
SELECT 
    CAST(to_date(CONCAT(year,'-',IF(LENGTH(month)=1,CONCAT(0,month),month), 
    '-',IF(LENGTH(day)=1,CONCAT(0,day),day))) AS TIMESTAMP) as theDate,
    temp AS temp
FROM oshkosh
WHERE temp != -9999
) as o
```

Comment: So it gave a new error:
``` Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:52 cannot recognize input near 'INTERVAL' '6' 'DAY' in windowframeboundary ```

Also, more context/reminder, there are multiple temperature readings per day so I'm also concerned that the INTERVAL 6 DAY portion isn't finding a new "day" before the 6 rows are done. There are 28 readings for the first day of the dataset (2000-01-01)

Comment: Ou, you're right this ```interval``` thing is not available in hive. You can replace it with numeric values, and run it over unix_timestamp.

Comment: the issue with that is there are varying numbers of temperature readings per day. day 1 has 28, day 2 has 44... I've also found out that my date field is still a string, so the to_date(from_unixtime... call isn't behaving as expected.

Comment: You need to convert it to epoch i.e. int and then use range

Comment: I need to convert the date field into epoch? I really appreciate your help but am pretty new so I would appreciate any concrete examples of what you're saying.

Comment: also, per this article, INTERVAL is available to HIVE and I think i'd be the most straightforward https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-TimestampstimestampTimestamps

Comment: Not in windowing function though, just as a type. I modified my code. I have no way of testing it at the moment.

Comment: Maybe there's an easy way to convert it to epoch-format interval, but that should then be equivalent to just taking ```6*24*60*60``` anyways

Comment: Glad it worked. Please consider upvoting and mark this post as an answer to close it off.